# What do we call those who are knowledgable but tend to forget it sometimes?

Tags: scripture

In general ,in Hindu culture, what do we call those beings who are highly knowledgeable but tend to forget the knowledge sometimes ?

Comment: highly knowledgeable but tend to forget the knowledge sometimes is a state, in which the bearer of the knowledge is least bothered about scholarly achievement.  He/she is called a  **Jnani** /REALISED one.  Only a person, who clamours for recognition for his/her scholarly achievements, will work hard to remember everything that is learnt.

Comment: Please post as an answer. Thank you.